# Rails 3 caches_page writes to file but does not read from cache on subsequent hits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, heroku

I'm implementing basic page caching for my application and even though I see the cache being written, subsequent requests do not read from the cached file.

The server log reports that the cache file is indeed created in the proper location as defined in the environment configuration.

I'm guessing this is related to the web server, so maybe this is even normal from the standard WEBrick server?

Comment: If you're running in development, have you enabled caching? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#basic-caching

Comment: Yes. And action caching works fine. As I stated it does correctly write the page cache file at the right location, it just does not read from it on subsequent displays.

Comment: Are you writing the file to somewhere other than the default `public` dir?

Comment: Oooh... yeah that must be it. I'm hosting on Heroku so I can only write to the Rails.root/tmp directory. I'll have to setup a middleware. Not too sure exactly how but I have it working for compass, which has similar limitations. I was just at least expecting some mention from WEBrick about the file path if that were the problem, but it most like is. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think WEBrick even notices, it just checks `public`, then passes the request on to rails when it doesn't find a match.

Comment: Anyone ever find a good solution to this? Can WEBrick be configured to check multiple directories?

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this with Heroku too. Heroku [addresses](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching) this by recommending you set a Cache-Control header in your controller action. Here's the example they give.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=300'
    render :text => "Rendered at #{Time.now}"
  end
end
```

What will happen is Heroku will pick up the header and cache the page in [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/)  for you. This only applies to the Aspen/Bamboo stack, not the new Cedar stack.

Comment: Great thanks. This seems to behave the same as when using caches_action, right?

Comment: It's more like page caching, since Varnish will actually serve the cached page. Action caching still goes through Rails' router, while using this method the request wont hit Rails at all.